# Can we make Multi line mat-label

Tags: html, css, angular-material

My label is a bit long so i want to make it multiline. Is there way that i can play with css to achieve it. Here is my code

```
 <div class="col-sm-4 require" click="onClick($event)">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <mat-label>What cultural background or ethnicity do you identify with?</mat-label>
          <mat-select autofocus formControlName="otherCulturalBackgroundID"
            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && formControls.otherCulturalBackgroundID.errors }" required>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let race of masterRace" [value]="race.id" (click)="onClick($event)">
              {{race.value}}
            </mat-option>
            
          </mat-select>
          <mat-error *ngIf="formControls.otherCulturalBackgroundID.errors">
            Please select other cultural backgrounds
          </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
```

this is how it looks. The label cuts of when its long
[image]

And i tried using this css.Mat-label goes multiline but it overlaps with below option.

```
.mat-form-field-label {
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

This is how it looks after using the above css. How can i solve this issue
[image: after css]

Comment: Guess you probably need to override a fixed height as well.

Comment: for the mat-label?

Comment: Don't know, can't find an example that actually uses this kind of label, right now. Should not be too hard to figure out using your browser dev tools though, I'd expect.

Comment: I have fixed the issue after overiding this css. .mat-form-field-infix {
    display: block;
    flex: auto;
    position: unset !important;
    min-width: 0;
    width: 180px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}